# npm start - errors and failure to load modules for Foundation Emails project

Tags: gulp, zurb-foundation, npm-start

I am starting a new project with Zurb's Foundation for Emails. I have followed instructions, installed Node.js (11.5), Homebrew, and Git. Created a new project with "foundation new" and selected the Email option. I named the project and saved it, cd'd into it, and my next step is to run "npm start", and I get this error:

[image: npm start error]

I am very new to this and I have no idea what these errors mean or how to solve them. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install gulp and gulp-cli globally.

`npm i -g gulp gulp-cli`

Comment: I got like 3 pages of errors after typing that in.  This is the first one: node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@11.5.0 (node-v67 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64' 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0

Comment: This means that you havd once installed npm with sudo or something else has changed the owners. sudo should have never be used as this produces such issues. Either uninstall npm and node and reinstall without sudo, change / check the owners (user & group) of the paths or try it with `sudo npm i ...` but I do not recommend tbis.

Comment: Also it's better to use Node.js 10 which is one of the LTS branches.

Comment: Thanks, I uninstalled Node and put on 10.15 - I get this now: Alexandrus-MacBook-Pro-2:test123 alexcrisan$ npm i -g gulp gulp-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

Comment: Did you uninstall npm and delete these folders before installing Node and npm again? This is still a perission issue with npm like before.

Comment: I recommend to install Node with Homebrew which also installs npm. Or nodenv / nvm.

Comment: Thank you! Before, I uninstalled Node, but apparently all the folders were still there, even though node -v and npm -v came up with nothing. So I had to show the hidden  folders in order to find them. I looked through everything manually and deed anything with node or npm. I took your advice and am using Homebrew to install Node and NPM. It is taking a very long time, first it updated Homebrew (took 17 minutes), and now it's apparently installing Node, 0.1 % at a time. Hopefully this works. I appreciate your support!

Comment: Well... nothing was installed. No node or npm. ==> Pouring node-11.6.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link node
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.6.0: 3,938 files, 46.6MB
==> Caveats
==> icu4c
... continued no more chars left.

Comment: Did you try `brew link node`? That systemtap is not writable is probably a well known problem.

Comment: Alexandrus-MacBook-Pro-2:test123 alexcrisan$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.6.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

Comment: I'll keep trying things... it's crazy how complicated this has to be. There should be 1 universal programing language smh. This is what makes me hate coding.

Comment: Do you mean Java and C(++)? Well the issue with permissions and so on should be solved in another question but I'm sure that others had the same issue and there are already many solutions. The original issue with gulp should be solved by following the gulp setup instructions on the gulp.js website (globally install the cli).